# Angular application shows blank page on addition of a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

For the purpose of this question I have created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhj99b?file=src/app/app.component.html). I was learning about services and wanted to incorporate a service into my application.However, as soon as I declare a constructor including my service, my application starts displaying a blank page.

Here's my app.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedInfoService } from './shared-info.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular Dev';

  private listOfComponents: any[];
  customerType: boolean;
  customerName: string;

  constructor(private _service: SharedInfoService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.customerName = 'Angular Customer';
  }
}
```

and here's my shared-info.service.ts

:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedInfoService {
  constructor() {}

  public name = 'Darth Vader';
}
```

I am not able to figure out why just adding this constructor creates a blank page. Ass soon as I comment  the constructor out the page goes back to displaying what it should. Which obviously would halt my progress with my application.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Probably you forgot to provide service in module. You can check console in dev tools - probably you will see an error there

Comment: yes, I imported it in the app.module.ts file, usually IDE did that part so I didnt notice

Answer (score 2):

Because you didnt declare how your service should be created/provided. Either use

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn:"root"
})
export class SharedInfoService {
  constructor() {}

  public name = 'Darth Vader';
}
```

or add provider to your modules

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  providers: [SharedInfoService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Both will work (even if used together)

Comment: thank you, I took the second approach and it worked :)